# Repeated measures (across space) linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures

I have a data set which I think requires an linear mixed model to analyze, but am unsure about some details. Below is a brief description of the experiment:

I have data from ~ 30 mice half of which are male and half of which are female. I have a behavioral measure that I'd like to predict based on activated cells in the brain. I performed a cluster analysis on cells counts in 485 regions and a SVD on each cluster, which leaves me with 9 repeated measures (I am only using the first singular value for each cluster) and sex as a between groups variable. I would think that the model should be:

lmer(Behavior ~ sex + cluster + (sex * cluster) + (cluster | mouse)

My only concern is that my DV is not a repeated measure. My question is then if this is the correct approach. See the data below:

[image]

edit: Reposting data for a single mouse in response to the first comment

```
`Behavior   Cluster Sex Mouse
28  -0.038136592    0   1
28  -0.023112313    0   1
28  -0.222644927    0   1
28  -0.208861993    0   1
28  -0.269723875    0   1
28  -0.062751677    0   1
28  -0.191682896    0   1
28  -0.245295508    0   1
28  -0.190930967    0   1`
```

Comment: Is each row in the dataset one mouse ? Where is the variable "cluster" in the dataset and what is it exactly ? How do the 9 "repeated measures" which I assume are the columns in the image with decimals enter the model `Behavior ~ sex + cluster + (sex * cluster) + (cluster | mouse)`. And the outcome variable `Bahaviour` (is it `Attack Durati` in the picture. or something else) ?

Comment: Yes each row is a mouse  The data re-arranged for a single mouse is now in the original post.

Comment: Ok but I asked 4 questions and you've only answered the first.

Comment: The outcome variable is Behavior, as indicated in the edited post. The variable cluster in the dataset is the column which says "cluster", as indicated in the edited post. Cluster is the first singular value of a module that was identified by using a clustering algorithm on the cell count data. There were 9 modules/cluster detected, and each value is the first singular value for said module/cluster.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I get the picture now. I don't think a mixed model is appropriate here since you don't have repeated measures. The 9 clusters are really just 9 variables for the same mouse so a model with fixed effects for those 9 variables plus sex would be appropriate but with only 30 mice, you will need to use some kind of penalization.

Comment: ok, thanks. when you say "some kind of penalization" do you mean some thing like LASSO?

Comment: Yes that's what I was thinking of. Are the clusters correlated with each another ? If not then you might also consider just retaining the ones with the highest correlation with the outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments a mixed model is not appropriate here, since there are no repeated measures of the outcome.

The 9 clusters are really just 9 variables for the same mouse so a model with fixed effects for those 9 variables plus sex would be appropriate but with only 30 mice, you will need to use some kind of penalization such as LASSO.

Also if the clustering algorithm used to find the 9 clusters results in orthogonal clusters  - is the 9 cluster variables are uncorelated with each other (or their sample correlations are low) then you could just fit a model with, say, the 3 clusters with the highest correlation with the response.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The clusters aren't orthogonal. Three of the nine are correlated (r =.6-.7) however the others aren't (r < .4)